# pandas groupby по нескольким колонкам + фильтрация

Tags: python, pandas

Игрушечный датасет для примера.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 30 
data = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'column1': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n),     
        'column2': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n),  
        'column3': np.random.randint(1, 4, size=n)
        })


    column1 column2 column3
0   2       7       1
1   5       1       1
2   9       9       3
3   2       3       2
4   4       6       3
```

Нужно получить новый столбец `column4`, сгруппированный по `column1` и `column2`, и с условием `column3 == 1`.

Если делаю с группировкой по одной колонке - то всё ок: `data.column1.map( train.groupby(train['column1'][train['column3'] == 1]).size()).fillna(0)`

Пытался применять filter, loc, не получается.

Comment: не совсем понял. что мешает сначала выделить условие с column3, а потом группировку делать: `df["column4"] =  df.loc[df["column3"]==1].groupby(["column1", "column2"]).transform(sum)` ?

Comment: Если в `df` больше колонок, то ошибка `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed n, placement implies 1` - `n` тут это число колонок в `df`. Если в начале строки ставлю `df[["column1", "column2", "column3"]].loc[df......` то заходит. Но потом этот результат нельзя обработать - в моём случае разделить на результат другой колонки - та же ошибка  `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed n, placement implies 1`, где `n` это число строк. Отобразить через map на весь датафрейм тоже не получается.

Comment: на какой код именно ругается интерпретатор этой ошибкой?

Comment: Весь массив данных (`column1 ... column10`) не принимался, надо указывать только колонки, участвующие в обработке. В конце не `sum` а `count`. Если в одну строку то не отрабатывал `fillna()`. Также не получалось сразу поделить на число (значение другой колонки). Пришлось сделать в две строки:
СТРОКА_1: `data['column4'] =  data[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].loc[train["column3"] == 0].groupby(['column1', 'column2']).transform('count')`
СТРОКА_2: `data['column4'] = data['column4'].fillna(0) / data['column5']`

Comment: судя по симптомам, у вас "неочищенные данные" в какой-то из колонок. но не имея перед глазами конкретного датасета, тяжело угадывать.

Comment: Нет, я специально сделал игрушечный датасет, собственно как в начале топика. Но уже неважно, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Вынужден снова Вас спросить, несколько дней не могу справиться с парой строчек кода.
Если делаю как описано:
`data['column4'] =  data[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].loc[train["column3"] == 0].groupby(['column1', 'column2']).transform('count')`
то получаю в колонке `data['column4']` некоторое значение, например `'3'`.
Если условие не выполняется, т.е. `loc[train["column3"] != 0]`, то там будет `NaN`.
Как мне подобраться к этим ячейкам с NaN'ами и вписать туда полученное значение '3'?

Comment: ну вот опять - у вас выборка идет из одного датафрейма по индексу другого - выбираете из data по индексу из train. я вам предлагаю выложить оба датафрейма на файлообменник, чтобы можно было работать с реальными данными. иначе, это получается лечение по фотографии...

Comment: Виноват, ввёл в заблуждение. Теперь пишу всё набело.
Создание датасета

`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np`

`n = 30 
data = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'column1': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n),     
        'column2': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n),  
        'column3': np.random.randint(1, 4, size=n),
        'column4': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n),
        'column5': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n),
        'column6': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n),
        'column7': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n)
        })`

Comment: Постановка проблемы: 
Код `data['column4'] =  data[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].loc[train["column3"] == 0].groupby(['column1', 'column2']).transform('count')`
даёт в колонке `data['column4']` некоторое значение, например `'3'`. Если условие не выполняется, т.е. `loc[data["column3"] != 0]`, то там будет `NaN`. 
Как мне подобраться к этим ячейкам с `NaN`'ами и вписать туда полученное значение `'3'`?

Comment: вы можете редактировать свой вопрос.

Comment: и все-таки, вы делаете выборку из data по индексам из train. так и задумано? `data[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].loc[train["column3"]`

Comment: Я бы и рад делать по всему датасету `data.loc[train["column3"]` но не пускает. Ну это сейчас неважно.

Comment: ничего не понятно. кто кого куда не пускает? вы понимаете, что вводите вопросом в заблуждение. у вас column3 в вопросе - в датасете data. а выборку вы делаете по индексам train. а этого датасета нету в вопросе. и это _важно_

Comment: omg ... прошу прощения, опять закрался `train` вместо `data'. Всё единоообразно, везде только `data`.  
  `data['column4'] =  data[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].loc[data["column3"] == 0].groupby(['column1', 'column2']).transform('count')`. При попытке запустить `data.loc[data["column3"]` возвращает ошибку, но это сейчас неважно, `data[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].loc[data["column3" == 0 ]` работает корректно. Прошу прощения за небрежность, никакого `train`, только `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итого

```
data['res2'] = ''

data['res1'] = data[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].loc[data['col3'] == 0].groupby(['col1', 'col2']).transform('count') 

for i in range(0, data.shape[0], 1):
        if data['res1'][i] in range(1, 100, 1): 
            for j in range(0, data.shape[0], 1):
                if data['col1'][j] == data['col1'][i] and data['col2'][j] == data['col2'][i]:
                    data['res2'][j] = data['res1'][i]  

data['res2'] = data['res2'].replace('', 0)
```

Очень плохой код, знаю((
Но всё работает

Answer (score 1):

Комментариев к вопросу слишком много. попробуем пошагово решать проблему в ответе:

При:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
n = 30
data = pd.DataFrame({'column1': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n),
                     'column2': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n),
                     'column3': np.random.randint(0, 4, size=n),
                     'column4': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n),
                     'column5': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n),
                     'column6': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n),
                     'column7': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n)})
```

у меня отлично работают выборки:

```
data.loc[data['column3']!=0, ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']]
```

и

```
data.loc[data['column3']==0, ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']]
```

теперь можно делать нужную вам группировку:

```
data['res'] = data.loc[data['column3']==0, ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].groupby(['column1', 'column2']).transform('count')
```

```
    column1  column2  column3  column4  column5  column6  column7  res
0         7        3        1        8        7        7        1  NaN
1         4        7        2        8        7        6        3  NaN
2         8        5        3        3        9        8        2  NaN
3         5        9        0        1        3        9        5  1.0
4         7        7        1        8        7        5        6  NaN
5         3        2        3        3        1        1        7  NaN
6         7        4        0        3        4        3        4  1.0
7         8        9        3        1        4        8        7  NaN
и т.д.
```

проблема в том, что группы заполняются случайно, одним методом заполнить NaN не получится. Если у вас нет четкого регламента заполнения, то можно сделать так:

```
data['res'] = data['res'].fillna(method="ffill").fillna(method="bfill")
```

```
    column1  column2  column3  column4  column5  column6  column7  res
0         7        3        1        8        7        7        1  1.0
1         4        7        2        8        7        6        3  1.0
2         8        5        3        3        9        8        2  1.0
3         5        9        0        1        3        9        5  1.0
4         7        7        1        8        7        5        6  1.0
5         3        2        3        3        1        1        7  1.0
6         7        4        0        3        4        3        4  1.0
7         8        9        3        1        4        8        7  1.0
8         5        2        0        5        5        6        8  1.0
9         4        9        1        7        7        8        1  1.0
10        8        5        2        9        7        9        6  1.0
11        8        2        0        7        4        4        8  1.0
12        3        4        3        9        7        1        5  1.0
13        6        7        1        8        3        1        4  1.0
14        5        8        0        2        6        4        2  2.0
15        2        3        3        1        2        7        6  2.0
16        8        1        3        7        9        2        6  2.0
17        6        4        3        7        5        3        1  2.0
18        2        2        0        8        6        1        9  1.0
19        5        8        0        5        4        5        6  2.0
20        1        4        0        3        7        1        3  1.0
21        6        2        2        8        9        8        4  1.0
и т. д.
```

то есть, сначала делаем forward fill, затем backward fill. можно и наоборот, но тогда получится другая колонка.

Comment: Во втором случае при `.transform('count')` будут подсчитаны строки, где выполняется условие `.loc`, в этих строках столбца будет некоторое значение `'n'`. В первом случае вместо этого значения будет NaN. Собственно вопрос: как при несоблюдении условия `.loc[ ... ]` (т.е. в первом случае) вписать в эти строки значение `'n'`, полученное при соблюдении условия?

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваше время, но ffill / bfill это немного не то. Видимо придётся писать сложную функцию обработки, составлять словарь что-то типа {[cl1, col2] : res }, чтото такое.